# calling php and javascript functions with one button

Tags: php, javascript, select

This is what I'm trying to achieve, but my Googling hasn't helped:

I have a button that adds a new row to a table dynamically. I also add a select component to a cell with the same action all in javascript. I'd like for that select component to populate with values from a sql select statement. Of course I don't want to define the connection to the DB in the JavaScript. So I was wondering if there was a way I could call a PHP function to retrieve the values then store it in variable within JavaScript.

PS I understand that PHP is server side as opposed to JS. But surely this is possible.

Comment: what you want is "AJAX". That means: create a PHP script that reads the data from the DB and echoes it in JSON format. Then with javascript you can load that script and parse the data.

Comment: are you using pure php or a framework?

Comment: @Tom Sarduy i think i'm using pure PHP, (i don't know), i've just started using php today :) i installed php5 on ubuntu if that helps

Comment: @TheBronx sounds pretty hectic! thanks :) i appreciate all the help, as long as i know this is possible, then i'll break my head over it! thanks for the guidance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here's a simple implementation of such a thing using jQuery's ajax and php.

html

```
<select data-source-url="/category/list"></select>
```

javascript using jQuery

```
$("select[data-source-url]").each(function(){
    var url = $(this).attr("data-source-url");
    var el = $(this);
    $.get(url, function(data){
        for (i=0;i<data.length;i++){
            el.append("<option>" + data[i] + "</option>");
        }
    },"json");
});
```

category/list endpoint (a php script)

```
$list = array();
$list[0] = "category 1";
$list[1] = "category 2";
$list[2] = "category 3";
$list[3] = "category 4";
$list[4] = "category 5";

echo json_encode($list);
```

a little explanation: what happens is a request being made via the JavaScript client to a php script, which returns an array of values in JSON (which is basically a javascript data-structure), those values are added to the select box dynamically.

Please note that on initial load of the page, the select box will be empty.

Comment: you can change the PHP script to receive $_GET parameters so that from javascript you can load `example.php?row=25` or something like that.

Comment: @Itai Sagi, Thanks so much for the suggestion! Very Userful! Helped me alot.

Answer (score 1):

yes ofcourse you can. for storing s php variable in a js ariable you can do like this.
before storing it into js variable store the required value in your php variable

```
var value = '<?php echo $value;?>';
```

Comment: And what does `$value` contain? All the rows in the table? I think AJAX would be better in this situation.

Comment: although @User has a very simple solution, I see where he's (or she) is going with this, I've only just leart that echo's from php aren't just for outputting text to the screen. #OldDogNewTrix, Thanks User

Answer (score 1):

Javascript cannot connect directly to a database.

You want [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29). A basic flow for this functionality looks like this.

1. Create a PHP script that connects to the database and gets the options for your select element (let's call it options.php). This script should fetch the options from the database and output them as a [JSON](http://www.json.org/) array.
2. In your javascript, you would create an ajax request to options.php. With the JSON data returned from that script, you would loop over each element and create and append a corresponding option element to the dom inside of your select element.

Also consider using [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/). It greatly simplifies ajax and provides a cross-browser solution.

Answer (score 1):

### Option 1

Pass a `php` array with all possible values to the client side using something like this on the client side:

```
var opt_values = [<?php echo $php_values; ?>]; //javascript array
```

or

```
var opt_values = <?php echo json_encode($php_values); ?>; //json object
```

### Option 2

Another way is making an ajax request. Write a php function that return a `JSON` object and then you can manipulate the result using jQuery ajax method:

**PHP function:**

```
$json = array();
$result = mysqli_query ($connection, $query);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array ($result))     
{
    $bus = array(
        'id' => $row['id'],
        'text' => $row['name']
    );
    array_push($json, $bus);
}

return = json_encode($json)
```

**Jquery**

```
$('#button-id').click(function(){
//adds a new row to a table dynamically
    $.ajax({
        type: "get",
        dataType: "json",
        url: "/get_values.php",
        success: function (response) {
            var $el = $("#myselect"); //get the select
            $el.empty(); // remove old options
            //Append the new values
            $.each(response, function(key, value) {
              $el.append($("<option></option>")
                 .attr("value", value.id).text(value.text));
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks Tom! Appreciate the suggestion! love the options! :)

Answer (score 0):

Just thought i'd put it out there since w3schools is my friend and i kinda follow what they're saying in this post.
[W3Schools PHP & AJAX communication](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp)